# Tensorflow: Generate Next Batch of data (in parallel) while the CNN/RNN trains

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

I am trying to train a complex neural network to detect captcha (just that my captcha is not in English, but in one of the Indian languages, like Telugu, Kannada, Devanagari, Persian, etc.)

My ‘dataset’ is artificially rendered. I render some words as images to a numpy array and then distort it. Then `yield` it to the `model.fit_generator` (or `model.fit`) function in `tensorflow` (along with the labels). I have a model based on CNNs, RNNs, followed by CTC loss, based on [this kaggle post](https://www.kaggle.com/aakashnain/building-a-captcha-ocr-in-tf2-0). It is all good, and trains, but I want to speed it up, exploiting obvious parallelisms.

Now I want to parallelize I am thinking something like this...

```py
def datagen(params):
    while True:
        image, text = cairo_draw_captcha()   # Code to generate the data
        yield image, text

model = get_cnn_lstm_ctc_model(model_params)
history = model.fit(datagen, steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=100)
```

Now I want to do something like... (pseudo-code for `spawn`, `collect` etc. I am not familiar with parallel processing in Python.)

```py
def datagen(params):
    queue = [cairo_draw_captcha()]
    while True:
        parallel_process = spawn(cairo_draw_captcha, queue)   # Spawn a parallel process to generate data
        yield queue.pop(0)
        parallel_process.collect() # Make sure the parallel process is done

model = get_cnn_lstm_ctc_model(model_params)
history = model.fit(datagen, steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=100)
```

Comment: To accelerate the training Tensorflow provides `tf.distribute.Strategy` library to run the code on multiple processing unit. For more details on library find  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training. Thanks!